# Powershell - How To Run A Monitoring Folder Script From A Batch In The Background?

Tags: powershell, process, monitor

I wrote a PowerShell script that monitors a specific folder for changes such as : creating  /deleting / renaming items.

Then it writes all those actions into a log file. It works fine. The only problem is, that it works only when the console is on.

Whenever I'm trying to run it using a batch file it doesn't seems to be working (writing to a log file). I'm trying to run it as a background process.

This is the monitoring function :

```
function CreateMonitor($folder)
{    
    $folder = 'C:\Users\...\Monitored Folder\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor. 
    $filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.          

    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 

    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
    Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\...\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}                 
}
```

This is the batch file content :

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file C:\Users\....ps1
```

How to make it run in the background / as a process?

Comment: Don't use write-host.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment, its likely the `Write-Host` statement is breaking your script because that tries to write output to the console and when you run the script with no window there is no console to write to.

Best practice would be to change this to a `Write-Verbose` and then add `[cmdletbinding()]` to your function. Then if/when you want to see the statement, you call your function with a `-Verbose` switch:

```
function CreateMonitor
{    
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        $folder = 'C:\Users\...\Monitored Folder\',
        $filter = '*.*'
    )

    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 

    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
    Write-Verbose "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
    Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\...\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}                 
}
```

You need to have `Param()` block to use `[cmdletbinding()]` so i've moved your `$folder` parameter in to this. I've also set its default value here, where as in your original function you were overriding it (if it had been set via a parameter). It also seemed to me to make sense to have `$filter` as a parameter also.

If you now want to see the verbose output you would simply invoke your function via:

```
CreateMonitor -Verbose
```

Of course you just wouldn't use this switch when running it in the background as there would be no where to see the output.

For more info on why using `Write-Host` is generally discouraged see this blog post from the creator of PowerShell: http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: I have deleted the write-host part. But the behavior seems to be the same. There is no change. It still doesn't write to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, I'm assuming your file looks something like

```
function CreateMonitor { ... }
CreateMonitor
```

If this is the case then it is failing because once the ps1 file executes it then goes and exits since no further commands are needed.

If you add

```
while ($true) {} # alternately add Start-Sleep -s 1
```

Then the ps1 file will remain running and won't exit the moment it successfully creates the filewatcher.